# Javascript + Jquery + Sharepoint date format error 2020-10-01T19:01:00.0000000Z;2020-10-01T04:00:00.0000000Z

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

We have a content editor webpart that uses javascript to render the page contents from a SharePoint list. There is a managed property in this list for a field called "PublicationDate".

Recently the date format changed from its normal "Friday, September 11, 2020" to now display in this format "2020-10-01T19:01:00.0000000Z;2020-10-01T04:00:00.0000000Z".

I am a noob at Javascript/Jquery, and I have tried to change the date format with some javascript functions e.g ToDate() to no avail because I don't really understand how this code works. If someone could help me to get the date back into the correct format it would be very much appreciated!

Here is the code for the page...

```
<script language="javascript">
var sourceID = "2eef3ece-f1d5-45e1-a124-608dbcfbfdr4";
var myQuery = 'ContentType:NewsPost';
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);

keywordQuery.set_queryText(myQuery);
keywordQuery.set_sourceId(sourceID);

var properties = keywordQuery.get_selectProperties();
properties.add('RefinableDate00'); //This is the date value in a managed property

var sortproperties = keywordQuery.get_sortList();
sortproperties.add('RefinableDate00', 1); 

var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
var results2 = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess2, onQueryFail);

//format the Pubication date
var myDates = this.RefinableDate00.split(" | ");
var myNewPubDate = myDates[0];  //I am confused as to why there is a what i presume to be an array value [0] here?

myHTML += "<div class='postPubDateHome'>" + myNewPubDate + "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the date format.
[image]

CODE:

```
new Date("2020-10-01T19:01:00.0000000Z").format('dddd, MMMM, dd ,yyyy')
```